# G++ - Cannot find -latk-1.0 and -lgdk_pixbif-2.0 (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++

I am trying to compile a c++ program using g++ statically so I can execute it on another machine (that does not have the ability/memory to compile).

I have successfully linked all of the libraries so far however I am running into the error messages:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbif-2.0
```

I can't find any leads to install these libraries so they can be statically compiled (The program compiles successfully when dynamic but the other machine is missing the dependencies.)

Another alternative solution would be to mark `-latk-1.0` and `-lgdk_pixbif-2.0` to be dynamic - would that be successful? If so how?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not an Ubuntu user, but you may want to try your Google-fu and see what package provides those libraries. If they're not available as static libraries through apt, you may have to compile them yourself.